# Trying to make anythingslider video responsive

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to make the video responsive. Video works fine without trying to make it responsive: http://inetwebdesign.com/AnythingSlider-master/video2.html#&panel1-1, but when I put expand: true, the images do not scale well, and the video starts flickering: http://inetwebdesign.com/AnythingSlider-master/video3.html#&panel1-1. I have tried to put media queries in anythingslider.css with a variety of heights and widths, but the slider does not respond to media queries in the css. I also tried max-width:100%, height:auto, or height at a specific px, still nothing.

Any ideas on how to make this work?

I am trying to make it responsive like http://inetwebdesign.com/responsive-video-tests/responsive-video-demo/flexslider/woothemes-FlexSlider-ca347d4/demo/video2.html which has its own issues.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would put this in a comment- as it's not a full answer - but I don't have enough rep - sorry about that.

I think I would try manipulating this in javascript instead of expect it to work automatically.

Resizing the embed element seems to be working fine, so I would try to do the following:
1)Calculate the initial window size
2)On resize
    a)resize the li that contains the item proportionately
    b)resize the embed element in your iframe

I think this should work without any flickering.

Thanks!